# Laravel relationship 2 layers

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have my database (=model) structure like that:

```
game:  
    lot (typeof Lot)
    places (array type of Place)
         place_id // just a number of a lot in some game
         user_id
```

What should I do to call in everywhere like this:

```
User::find(1)->games() // returns Game collection where user has places
```

?

Models are:

```
class Place extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['place_id', 'user_id', 'game_id'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function game() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Game::class);
    }
}
```

User:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'steam_id', 'avatar'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['remember_token'];

    /**
     * Get all of the tasks for the user.
     */
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SteamItem::class);
    }

    public function places() {
        return $this->hasMany(Place::class);
    }
}
```

The Game:

```
class Game extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['lot_id'];

    public function lot() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Lot::class);
    }

    public function places() {
        return $this->hasMany(Place::class);
    }
}
```

Now I use this code in my User class:

```
public function games() {
    return Game::with(['places' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', $this->id);
    }]);;
}
```

It doesn't work, because I need to make it as a relationship method, but `with` method returns a query builder.

In the finals I must call `$user->games` and it should return me all the games user linked to through place.

Comment: read about with() function http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Yes, I heard about it. But as I recognized it, it will only work in my controller, and I want to implement it as a relationship. Is it possible?

Comment: can you show us your models?

Comment: sorry I cant really understand you.. I can tell you that you need to add relationship from user to game. and from game to lot and places. than you can do User::find(1)->with('games','games.lot','games.places')

Comment: okay, I'll try to explain. I need to show (in loop) all the lots I play with. For example: I paid for 1 place in a Game. Game has a Lot. Lot has imageUrl property. I need to show N pictures in my profile with calling `@foreach (Auth::user()->games() as $game) <img src='{{$game->lot->imageUrl}}' />@endforeach`, but **User** has only `hasMany(Place::class)`. And Place has **game** (Game) property.

Comment: everything is in the docs.. try to do User::find(1)->with('places','places.game','places.game.lot')

Comment: Okay. Can I call this in the model class? Because I need **this**. :)

Comment: I can't understand your questions, it's sound like you need to practice some basic stuff about relations, anyway you can use the With() method on the model, if $this is the model so yes it has the with method :)

Comment: Sorry man but now I'm getting this error: `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` where method is: `public function games() {
        return Game::with(['places' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', $this->id);
        }])->get();
    }` Hey `with` method returns query builder but I need a relation

Comment: can you edit your question and add the relevent info to it? how you call the games() function?

Comment: and please only in english most of us can't read other languages :)

Comment: sorry, I'm russian. Just let me know where did I put some russian words?)

Comment: on what line you getting the error?

Comment: User's games() method's return stub generates the error. Full error: `ErrorException in Model.php line 2717:
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation (View: D:\OpenServer\domains\steam-lottery.ru\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php) (View: D:\OpenServer\domains\steam-lottery.ru\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)`

Comment: app.blade.php is my base template, where I call `@if (count(Auth::user()->games))
                        <div class="lots">
                            @foreach (Auth::user()->games as $game)
                                <div class="lot">
                                    <img src="{{ $game->lot->getItem()->getClearUrl() }}" alt="">
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    @endif`

Comment: wow i am so lost in your code.. in your games function your should return $this->with(...

Comment: Hey @amirbar I just tried calling your 'User::find(1)->with('games','games.lot','games.places')' - this returns me again collection of **Place** items. I need to get a collection of **Game** items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I think I understand now.

User has many Place. Place belongs to User.
Place belongs to Game. Game has many Place.

You can try this:

```
$user = User::with('places.game.lot')->find(1);
```

This will fetch the User and eager load all the relationships. Because Place belongsTo a Game, which in turn belongs to Lot, you can then do this:

```
@foreach ($user->places as $place)
    <img src="{{$place->game->lot->imageUrl}}" />
@endforeach
```

Also, place is actually a pivot table, and you can take advantage of Eloquent's [many-to-many](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship, which I would recommend reading about.

Comment: That's my trouble - the **game** doesn't have `user_id`. Game `hasMany` **places**. And the place has `user_id`. And within my user model I should have games (relation) method which will return me all linked with user games. Node they they're linked through place :D Oh my gosh, it makes my headache. Pls:D Btw sry for my English, it's 4 o'clock here.

Comment: Hey I just tried calling `User::find(1)->with('games','games.lot','games.places')` - this returns me again collection of **Place** items. I need to get a collection of **Game** items

Comment: @Hiron123 I edited my answer. If I'm understanding this correctly, this solution should work for you.